# Twitter Bootstrap and RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have included my boot-strap gem in my gem file, and the css code seems to be working fine. But now I am trying to implement a dropdown menu, using `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`
but I have been told that I need to down load another *.js file from bootstrap. Aren't they all included in the gem? and is there a tutorial that can show me how to use the dropdown menus in RoR?

Edited:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Which bootstrap gem specifically did you use? Also, could you post the app/assets/javascripts/application.js? -- you need to add a require statement in that file.

Comment: i edited it so u can see

Answer (score 0):

Check out twitter-bootstrap-rails which has generators that will do the setup for you. The readme on the github page has all the instructions and there is also a link to a railscast where there are two videos explaining what to do.

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails